# Appcelerator [ERROR] : Invalid "--pp-uuid" after provisioning certificate update

Tags: appcelerator

I'm new to Appcelerator and Stackoverflow, so pardon my ignorance.

I have just updated my iOS provisioning certificate and now I get the following error.  Any ideas? I'm using SDK 5.0.0.GA and studio build 4.0.0.

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--pp-uuid" value "d806f6cb-f67e-40e5-a9f3-88b8af3bcfae"
For help, run: titanium help build
2016-01-16T21:08:11.950Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2016-01-16T21:08:11.951Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/rwhatcher/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2016-01-16T21:08:11.952Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  56550
```

Answer (score 12):

Did you look at Run Configurations... [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV4RL.png). You can change provisions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI60Z.png). Make sure have green check all.

Good luck.

Comment: All are green but i am still getting   the same error

Answer (score 4):

Welcome Robert, well you can try a fresh restart.

First look at your `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder and delete the deprecated provisions.

Then you go to your membership Apple account and create a new certificate (dev/prod) and a new provision profile linked to the certificate and your app id (e.g device/production). Remember to open the files certificate/provision at least one time.

After all, run a `appc ti clean` at your project root followed by `appc run -p ios -T device`. The CLI will ask for you choose the certificate and provision, then you choose the new ones and then it should works.

Comment: The user is using Studio, not CLI

Answer (score 1):

Also check in your `/library/mobileDevice/ProvisioningProfiles` folder, this is where the files are located after you've downloaded them and double clicked.

Sometimes I find there are multiple versions of the same provisioning file and appcelerator isn't using the most up to date one.  If you delete them, you'll need to download them again from ios dev center (this includes the development, distributon and app store files).