# Update titanium app - Invalid "--pp-uuid" value

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have to update an old project that was developed with titanium, but after a long time of researching I am not able to even run it in my device. 
That is why I have decided ask for help here.

The error message that I am getting is:

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--pp-uuid" value "0ca5b889-29b7-49f0-816b-29ec40783b84"
For help, run: titanium.js help build
```

I have read in another post in stackoverflow: [Appcelerator [ERROR] : Invalid "--pp-uuid" after provisioning certificate update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832388/appcelerator-error-invalid-pp-uuid-after-provisioning-certificate-update/34834054) that I have to look at Run Configurations and change provisions there to make sure have green check all.

That is done:
[image]

But I am still getting the error with the uuid, if I try to change the app id the I am getting the "Select Provisioning Profile" red, so I also can not run it.
Thoughts in what I can do?

Comment: do you have a valid provisioning profile with right certificates and device-id's embedded

Comment: @RenePot I had to create a new provisional profile and download it again to make it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem:
First I deleted all the provisions profiles, to make sure I am not using an old one:

```
rm  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*
```

Then I created a new certificate and a new provision profile linked to the certificate and the app id in the Apple membership account. And I download it an open, to be stored in the computer.

Now I clean and run the project again with the command line:

```
appc ti clean
appc run -p ios -T device.
```

I chose the certificate and provision already created and it finally works.

Comment: For me `appc ti clean` did not work, Project -> Clean in Appcelerator Studio did it for me!

Comment: Not sure why, because should be the same, instead with the command line with the IDE.  But thanks, that could helps more people